# Understanding this Graph: What is a PetaFlop?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I was looking at this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.14165.pdf) and came across this graph:

[image]

I am trying to understand the following two things about this graph:

- What is  PetaFLOP/s-days? I read that a PetaFLOP is 1,000,000,000,000,000 calculations (e.g. addition, subtraction). I am guessing that 10^2 would imply 100 * 1,000,000,000,000,000 calculations per day  - is this correct? Is there any difference between PetaFLOP/days and PetaFLOP/s-days? (I also find it interesting they are probably referring to "computer resources" as simply "compute")
- What does "C" stand for in L = 2.57 * C^-0.048? I am guessing that the "dotted line" probably refers to the "average loss" for different Neural Networks with differing amounts of Parameters - but what exactly does "C" stand for?
- Finally, is there a reason that "Validation Loss" is not expressed as a percentage? For instance, what is a Validation Loss of 3? Is a Validation Loss of 3 the same as a Loss of 30%? Or does Validation Loss simply refer to the value of the Loss Function obtained during the Validation stage of Cross Validation?

Thank you!

Comment: PetaFLOP/s-days most likely means 1 day of petaFLOPS, i.e. $8.64 \times 10^{19}$ floating point operations.

Comment: From the footnote of [this page](https://openai.com/blog/ai-and-compute/): "A petaflop/s-day (pfs-day) consists of performing $10^{15}$ neural net operations per second for one day, or a total of about $10^{20}$ operations."

Comment: thanks everyone! also - I am thinking that "loss" is on a logarithmic scale?